# How to check if a string matches a pattern in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to write a fold expression, but I can't get the regex to work.

The string I want to check for and the regex are:

```
# -- Heading 1 --
```

```
^.*-{2}\s([\_a-zA-Z0-9]\s*)+\s-{2}$
```

what syntax do I use to do the check?
I tried: (non seemed to work)

`if match(line , "\v regex") >= 0
 if line =~ "\v regex"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either `match()` or `=~`, but the regexp is wrong.

There is a lot to guess as I don't know all the potential input, but I think you meant:

```
^.*-\{2}\s\%([_a-zA-Z0-9]\+\s\)\+-\{2}$
```

Or a slightly different variant using character classes:

```
^\v.*-- [_[:alnum:][:blank:]]+--$
```

Or maybe using a negated collection (matching any character but `-`):

```
^\v# -- [^-]+ --$
```

Go wild!

Comment: Thanks. I tried all your regexes, but they also didn't work. Then I figured out the problem was that I had been wrapping them in double quotes. Changed them to single and thew worked fine.